# Why does replace not replace?

Tags: python

code:

```
a = 'g'
b = a.title()
b.replace(b, a)
print(b)
```

output: `G`

I think the output should be 'g' lowercase as the replace statement replaces the uppercase 'G' to lowercase one.

I am trying to solve a challenge in which I have to capitalize a string but not the one that starts with numerals?

Comment: replace is not "in place" it returns the replaced string. so do something like `c = b.replace(b, a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in python are immutable.
Functions that would change the string, return a new one instead.

You can read the reasons behind this choice in many articles, like
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/why-are-strings-in-python-immutable

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the value of `b.replace(b, a)` to the variable `b` before you print it.

```
a = 'g'
b = a.title()
b = b.replace(b, a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
g
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of replace need ot be reassign - because replace gives you a copy with the replaced changes - so it isnt in place!

```
a = 'g'
b = a.title()
b = b.replace(b, a)
print(b)
```